# php class should return JQ library single time when its calling multiple time in single template

Tags: ee2, php

i am using a php class that returns jquery library if the class calls multiple times on same page it should include that jquery library  single time .

it works if class called single times it works fine but if i call it multiple times it shows js conflict due to multiple times added of jquery library.

how can i make it sigle time include only whenever the class called multiple times....

Comment: Can't the [jQuery module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/jquery/index.html) help you? I'm sorry, but I never used it. Please, give it a try. If you still need to create your own, I can help you.

Comment: thanks robson...well its a good idea.

as of now i have found an another way to do this by passing parametrs (yes or no) from template.



it would be yes for first time calling the class and if yes add library and must be no to another class callings.

Comment: I gonna post a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [session cache](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#session-cache) to know what your plugin already did while loading the page. Unlike the [session class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html), which is new, the session cache is there by a long time. It's intended to avoid unnecessary repeated actions.

You can create a variable called, let's say, `jqueryfied`.

```
if ( ! ee()->session->cache('my_add-on_class', 'jqueryfied'))
{
   // add your code to include the jquery

   ee()->session->set_cache('my_addon_class', 'jqueryfied', true);
}
```

See? Now you add-on knows if it already included the jquery script on the page.

Comment: It's awesome ...

such a brilliant way  to do this ...

Thank You so much....

it make my plugin much familiar to users ...

thanx once again...

Comment: @user3440483, please, if my answer is right, mark it as right. There's a lot of already answered questions unmarked here and this make hard for us to find which still needs attention.

Thank you!